# Jetpack Compose - LazyColumn fails to show some items if I swipe fast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I just try scrolling a list with **LazyColumn**. Problem is, if i scroll fast, it doesn't work laggy but it skips some of items.
It can show all items when i scroll the screen slowly.

```
compose_ui_version = '1.2.1'
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
```

Here is my code :

```
    @Composable
    fun ListItemRowCompose(listItem : RegularListItem)
    {
        Card() {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
            {
                if(listItem.image?.imageId!! > 0)
                    Image(
                    painter = painterResource(listItem.image!!.imageId),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .size(40.dp)
                    )
                else
                    AsyncImage(model = listItem.image?.imageUrl,
                        contentDescription ="",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))


                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                Column {
                    Text(listItem.title)
                    Text(listItem.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun ListCompose(list : RegularList) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            items(list.items) { li ->
                ListItemRowCompose(listItem = li)
            }
        }
    }
```

What i mean :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember LazyColumn state like this, in order to not load image everytime you scrool up and down -> `rememberLazyListState().`

Comment: I don't understand how your answer fixes the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when device is in dark mode and we added support only to light mode  to fix the issue add the below line in your app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
     //Add this line
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```